# Passing string as arg to apply function

Tags: variables, quote, backquote

I want to call `clone-indirect-buffer` or `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window` within a function dependent on the prefix.  To do this, I assign the appropriate clone function to a variable using let.  However, when I try to abstract the name of the buffer I get a type error.

This simplified example works as expected, creating a buffer called "banana":

```lisp
(let* ((fun #'clone-indirect-buffer)
       (buf (apply fun '("banana" nil))))
  (switch-to-buffer buf))  ; #<buffer banana>
```

When I move the name "banana" into a variable, I get a type error:

```lisp
(let* ((name "banana")
       (fun #'clone-indirect-buffer)
       (buf (apply fun '(name nil))))
  (switch-to-buffer buf))

;; (wrong-type-argument stringp name)
```

I notice that quasi-quote produces the expected result:

```lisp
(let* ((name "banana")
       (fun #'clone-indirect-buffer)
       (buf (apply fun `(,name nil))))
  (switch-to-buffer buf)) ; #<buffer banana>
```

AFAICT, name is a string.  So, why the error?

Comment: `'(name nil)` does not substitute the value of `name` for the name itself.