# function accepts string literal, but not the result of expression

Tags: quote, backquote

In my `init.el` I have a series of programming language specific hooks that I use to add font-lock patterns (namely adding a header style font to some of my comments).  Here is an example for c-like languages:

```
;; I'm only showing one pattern for simplicity
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords
             nil
             '(("^/// \\(.*\\)" 1 'header-1-face prepend)
               ;; more patterns ...
               ))))
```

The pattern above will match if I have a C comment with 3 '/' at the start of the line.  `header-1-face` is a font face defined earlier using `defface`.  As I work in different languages I will add a language specific hook to my config, but since there is a lot of repeated code I though to write a function that takes two parameters: a comment string and a header string (eg for the above example it would be `"//"` and `"/"` respectively)

My naive attempt at this function essentially encapsulated the contents of the lambda and parameterized the variables.

```
(defun match-comment-headers (c h)
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(
     ;; ("^/// \\(.*\\)" 1 'header-1-face prepend) ;; This works
     ((format "^%s%s \\(.*\\)" c h) 1 'head-1-face prepend) ;; This does not
     )))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda () (match-comment-headers "//" "/")))
```

When using this as a hook, emacs interprets the first element of `((format "^%s%s \\(.*\\)" c h) 1 'head-1-face prepend)` as a function and yields an "invalid function" error.  Using a hard coded string literal will work, however, so the overall format of the function and hook seem to be working properly.  **So the question is: In function such as `font-lock-add-keywords` that accepts these regex patterns, how can I use a string that is the result of an expression instead of a string literal?**

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question, e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66621/passing-string-as-arg-to-apply-function (which itself is marked as a duplicate and points to additional questions of the same sort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: After seeing the accepted answer here and that other question, it does indeed solve my problem.  Thanks!  Although I will say that it wasn't initially obvious to me that this was the exact issue I was having.

Comment: Agreed - the same issue appears under somewhat different guises that make it difficult to understand that it *is* the same issue. Hindsight is essential :-) That's why there are so many duplicates!

Comment: Please consider deleting your question, based on its being a duplicate. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) code is *not* evaluated, so `format` is never called.

Use [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html):

```lisp
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   `((,(format "^%s%s \\(.*\\)" c h) 1 'head-1-face prepend)))
```